# While using a subquery inside the inner query, variable declared in outer query becomes unaccesible to inner queries inside it

Tags: c#, linq

My project has subqueries used inside nested Query.While using a subquery inside the inner query, variable declared in outer query becomes unaccesible to inner queries inside it.
Error found while debugging nested queries:
1. Unknown column 'Join3.appcategoryid' in 'field list'
2. Unknown column 'Extent1.taxonomyid' in 'where clause'

```
enter code here :
public static dynamic GetTaxonomies
(int businessUnitId, int memberId, string businessUnitType)
        {
            using (var db = new ProtocolManagementDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var taxonomies = (from taxonomy in db.taxonomies
                                  join businessUnitTaxonomy in db.businessunittaxonomies on taxonomy.taxonomyid equals businessUnitTaxonomy.taxonomyid
                                  let TaxonomyID = taxonomy.taxonomyid
                                  where businessUnitTaxonomy.businessunitid == businessUnitId
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      TaxonomyId = taxonomy.taxonomyid,
                                      TaxonomyName = taxonomy.taxonomyname,
                                      preferenceValue = db.userpreferences.Where(x => x.entitycolumnvalue == TaxonomyID &&
                                      x.memberid == memberId && x.entitytablename == "Taxonomy" && x.sequencenumber == 5)
                                      .Select(x => x.isvisible).FirstOrDefault()

                                      AppCategory = (from appCategory in db.appcategories
                                                     join appCategoryTaxonomy in db.appcategorytaxonomies on appCategory.appcategoryid equals appCategoryTaxonomy.appcategoryid
                                                     let AppCategoryID = appCategory.appcategoryid
                                                     where appCategory.parentappcategoryid == null &&
                                                     appCategory.appcategorylevel.Equals("AppCategoryName")
                                                     && appCategoryTaxonomy.taxonomyid == TaxonomyID &&
                                                     appCategoryTaxonomy.businessunitid == businessUnitId

                                                     orderby appCategory.name ascending
                                                     select new
                                                     {
                                                         AppCategoryId = appCategory.appcategoryid,
                                                         AppCategoryName = appCategory.name,

                                                         AppCategoryDeletionEnable = db.appcategories.Where(x => x.parentappcategoryid == AppCategoryID)
                                                         .FirstOrDefault() != null ? true : false

                                                         SubCategory = from subCategory in db.appcategories
                                                                       let SubCategoryID = db.appcategories.Where(x => x.appcategoryid == subCategory.appcategoryid).Select(x => x.appcategoryid).FirstOrDefault()
                                                                       where subCategory.parentappcategoryid == AppCategoryID && subCategory.businessunitid == businessUnitId
                                                                       orderby subCategory.name ascending
                                                                       select new
                                                                       {
                                                                           AppCategoryId = subCategory.appcategoryid,
                                                                           AppCategoryName = subCategory.name,
                                                                           Description = subCategory.description,
                                                                           IsGlobal = subCategory.isglobal,
                                                                           IsEnable = subCategory.isenable,
                                                                           ParentAppCategoryID = appCategory.parentappcategoryid,
                                                                                   SubCategoryDeleteEnable = db.protocolappcategories.Where(x => x.appcategoryid == SubCategoryID)
                                                                           .FirstOrDefault() != null ? true : false,

                                                                           AppCategoryLevel = subCategory.appcategorylevel,
                                                                           IsExpand = false,
                                                                       }
                                                    }).ToList()
                                  }).ToList();
                return taxonomies;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is error coming from one of the queries returning null?

Comment: None of the query returns NULL.
But the error occurs when we are using the MariaDB, the query works proper for PostGres and Sql Server Database.

Comment: Are you sure the data is the same in all the database?  The error is not what the title of the posting says.  The error is due to the columns in the database : 1. Unknown column 'Join3.appcategoryid' in 'field list' 2. Unknown column 'Extent1.taxonomyid'